# Why isn't my Div not inheriting height from html or body?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to set the landing-wrapper div too take up 100% of the screen for a landing page. All answers to similar questions say to set html/body height to 100%. I've already set the html and body height to 100%, but it doesn't work. I'm using React and importing a CSS file for each component. Is there a possibility the issue has something to do with that?

DevTools Inspector Screenshot:
[image]

I know my question is probably asked a lot, but I couldn't find any answers in any related question i found. if there is something else i did wrong for my question to be downvoted could someone let me know so i can learn to get better

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with that is your CSS itself.100% in this case is just the height of the .

Try the following CSS for landing wrapper div:

```
width:100%;
height:100vh;
display:block;
```

And no, if it was a React problem, it wouldn't apply any CSS at all.

Comment: Thanks, that works! What's the difference between vh and %? Why does it work with 100vh but not 100%?

Comment: 100% is the 100% height of the element. For example, if you have 1400x300 div tag and you say height:100%; the height will be 300px. 

100vh will fill the whole height visible in the viewport.